# Enable external HD after remote reboot

Tags: command-line, ssh, disk, hard-drive

Ran into this one tonight:

Was on my laptop, and ssh'd into my desktop to access files on my desktop's external HD.  So far, so good.  However, after remotely rebooting the desktop, the external HD was disabled - I had to physically go to the desktop and log-in in order to get back on the external drive.

Is there a way I can set up the external HD to always be on/mounted, even if no one is actually logged in on that machine?

Thanks in advance,

Joe

Answer (score 2):

Follow the information [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Fstab) to add the drive to your fstab and then you should be able to use it as you asked.

Comment: Thanks Roland, that was exactly what I was looking for =)